# Javascript: Sanitize markdown

Tags: javascript, parsing, markdown

I've got an article writed in markdown on my webpage and I want to show a short resume on the  index page.

The problem is that the body has got markdown, and I want to show plain text on the resume.

Ex:

> Article text: **Hello** *people*
>
> Resume text:  Hello people

How can I do that in Javascript?

Comment: Are You using any frameworks? jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i might do is parse the markdown as HTML, then take only the textual content of it.

Psudeocode:

```
htmlElement.innerHtml = markdown.parse(myMarkDownString);
var plaintext = htmlElement.innerText;
alert(plaintext);
```

Comment: Like the below answer, this suffers from the same severe vulnerability as below.

Answer (score -1):

**WARNING** This is an instant XSS attack and does nothing to sanitize the HTML, because it's being attached to the DOM. Please see comment.

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

How about

1. pasting the markdown HTML into the dom,
2. getting the contents with jQuery.text method
3. removing the temporary dom element

?

```
function sanitize( markdown ){

    var wrappedMarkdown = "<div id='temp'> "+ markdown +" </div>";

    var sanitized = $.trim( $( wrappedMarkdown ).appendTo("body").text() );

    $("#temp").remove();

    return sanitized;

}

sanitize( "<b>Hello</b> <i>people</i>" );
// Returns "Hello people"
```

Comment: This is an instant XSS, like `sanitize("<script>alert(1)</script>")`. This is a very bad answer, sorry.